# Reference to instance in owl:oneOf enumeration

Tags: rdf, owl

I want to restrict the instances of one of my OWL classes to be one of a number of enumerated individuals. In the standard I found [**oneOf** class expressions](https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-owl-guide-20040210/#EnumeratedClasses), such as the following.  As I understand the standard, we can only define *new* individuals in **oneOf** expressions. How can I reference individuals that have already been defined, though?

```xml
<owl:Class rdf:ID="WineColor">
  <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#WineDescriptor"/>
  <owl:oneOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
    <owl:Thing rdf:about="#White"/>
    <owl:Thing rdf:about="#Rose"/>
    <owl:Thing rdf:about="#Red"/>
  </owl:oneOf>
</owl:Class>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> As I understand the standard, we can only define new individuals in oneOf expressions.

This is not correct.  You can use any individuals in the oneOf expression.  For instance, here's an ontology (in Turtle and RDF/XML) with a class **Color** that contains **Red**, **Blue**, and **Green**, and then two enumerated classes **RedOrBlue ≡ { Red, Blue }**, and **RedOrGreen ≡ { Red, Green }**.

```
@prefix :      <http://stackoverflow.com/q/37419182/1281433/> .
@prefix rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix owl:   <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix xsd:   <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .

:Green  a       owl:NamedIndividual , :Color .

:RedOrGreen  a               owl:Class ;
        owl:equivalentClass  [ a          owl:Class ;
                               owl:oneOf  ( :Green :Red )
                             ] .

:Red    a       owl:NamedIndividual , :Color .

:RedOrBlue  a                owl:Class ;
        owl:equivalentClass  [ a          owl:Class ;
                               owl:oneOf  ( :Blue :Red )
                             ] .

:Color  a       owl:Class .

:Blue   a       owl:NamedIndividual , :Color .

:       a       owl:Ontology .
```

```xml
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
    xmlns="http://stackoverflow.com/q/37419182/1281433/"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#">
  <owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://stackoverflow.com/q/37419182/1281433/"/>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="http://stackoverflow.com/q/37419182/1281433/RedOrBlue">
    <owl:equivalentClass>
      <owl:Class>
        <owl:oneOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
          <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://stackoverflow.com/q/37419182/1281433/Blue">
            <rdf:type>
              <owl:Class rdf:about="http://stackoverflow.com/q/37419182/1281433/Color"/>
            </rdf:type>
          </owl:NamedIndividual>
          <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://stackoverflow.com/q/37419182/1281433/Red">
            <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://stackoverflow.com/q/37419182/1281433/Color"/>
          </owl:NamedIndividual>
        </owl:oneOf>
      </owl:Class>
    </owl:equivalentClass>
  </owl:Class>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="http://stackoverflow.com/q/37419182/1281433/RedOrGreen">
    <owl:equivalentClass>
      <owl:Class>
        <owl:oneOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
          <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://stackoverflow.com/q/37419182/1281433/Green">
            <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://stackoverflow.com/q/37419182/1281433/Color"/>
          </owl:NamedIndividual>
          <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://stackoverflow.com/q/37419182/1281433/Red"/>
        </owl:oneOf>
      </owl:Class>
    </owl:equivalentClass>
  </owl:Class>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Comment: I thought that reference to already defined individual could be done with rdf:resource attribute. In your example link to already defined "Red" individual is made with rdf:about attribute? Is it correct? To define and to reference we can use rdf:about attribute?

Comment: @DenisSokolov rdf:resource is used when identifying the object of a triple, e.g., in `<owl:NamedIndividual ...> <rdf:type rdf:resource="..."/></owl:NamedIndividual>`, whereas `rdf:about` is used in the subject, e.g., `<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="...">...</owl:NamedIndividual>`.  It doesn't have anything to do with whether things have been "defined" earlier or not.  RDF/XML is a very complex syntax with lots of edge cases.  It's much better to use a human readable format like Turtle, and convert to RDF/XML if you need it.